# Issue with generating a table in php

Tags: php, html-table

How to adjust the following code?

I need to create a table (6x6) in a way that:

- The first row would contain 6 random numbers from 10 to 19
- The second row would contain 6 random numbers from 20 to 29
- The third row would contain 6 random numbers from 30 to 39
- The fourth row would contain 6 random numbers from 40 to 49
- The fifth row would contain 6 random numbers from 50 to 59
- The sixth row would contain 6 random numbers from 60 to 69

The code has been made in a way that, per row, six numbers has been selected from 10 random numbers, and those six numbers are placed in a table.

But I just heard from the teacher that a table needs to be created first (6x6), then a number has to be generated randomly cell by cell, and if the number is already present it has to be ignored (there cannot be repeated numbers).

How to adjust the following code (I just do not know it anymore):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Bingo</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$omvang = 5; // grootte v/d bingo kaart (2..9)
$trekkingen = 30; // aantal getrokken getallen

// initialiseer kaart
$kaart = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $omvang; $i++) {
    // definieer range v/d regel
    $regel = range($i * 10, $i * 10 + 9);
    // random volgorde
    shuffle($regel);
    // voeg de eerste {$omvang} cijfers toe aan de kaart
    $kaart[$i - 1] = array_slice($regel, 0, $omvang);
}

// bepaal trekking reeks
$trekking = range(10, $omvang * 10 + 9);
// randomize volgorde
shuffle($trekking);
// pak de eerste {$trekkingen}
$trekking = array_slice($trekking, 0, $trekkingen - 1);

// teken kaart en bewaar score
$score = array();
echo "<table style='border:1px solid blue;'>";
for ($y = 0; $y < $omvang; $y++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($x = 0; $x < $omvang; $x++) {
        $score[$y][$x] = 0;
        echo "<td>";
        echo $kaart[$y][$x] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>

</body>

</html>
```

This first piece of code makes part of a big piece of code for a Bingo play; and this is the first issue I am running against.

2.0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Bingo</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$rijen = array();
for($rij = 1; $rij <= 6; $rij++) {
    $rijen[$rij] = array();
    for($kolommen = 0; $kolommen < 6; $kolommen++) {
        do {
            $tabel = rand($rij * 10, ($rij * 10) + 9);
        } while(in_array($tabel, $rijen[$rij]));
        $rijen[$rij][$kolommen] = $tabel;
    }
}

$trekking = array();
for($trek = 11; $rij <= 70; $rij++) {
    $trekking[$trek] = array();
    for($kolom = 0; $kolom < 6; $kolom++) {
        do {
            $trektabel = rand($rij * 10, ($rij * 10) + 9);
        } while(in_array($tabel, $trekking[$trek]));
        $trekking[$trek][$kolommen] = $trektabel;
    }
}

$score = array ();
foreach($rijen as $r){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($r as $cel) {
        if (in_array($rijen[$rij][$kolommen], $trekking[$trek][$kolommen])) {
            // zit in de trekking:
            $score[$rij][$kolommen]=1;
            echo "<td style='background:blue;color:white;border:1px solid black;'>";
        else {
            $score[$rij][$kolommen]=0;
            echo "<td style='border:1px solid blue;'>" . $cel . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

</body>

</html>
```

3.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bingo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Bingokaart waarop BINGO is gevallen</h2>
<?php
function ishetBingo($tabelletje, $nummers,&$Rrij,&$Rkol) {
    $Rrij=
    $Rkol=
    $tabelRijen = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
    $tabelKolommen = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
    $voltooid = false;
    foreach($tabelletje as $rij => $kolommen) {
        foreach($kolommen as $kol => $nummer) {
            if(in_array($nummer, $nummers)) {
                $tabelRijen[$rij]++;
                $tabelKolommen[$kol]++;
                if($tabelRijen[$rij] == 6 ){
                  $voltooid = true;
                  $Rrij = $rij;  
                }
                if($tabelKolommen[$kol] == 6){
                  $voltooid = true;
                  $Rkol = $kol;   
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return $voltooid;
}
// initialiseer kaart
$kaart = array();
for ($rijen = 0; $rijen < 6; $rijen++) {
    $kaart[$rijen] = array();
    for($k = 0; $k < 6; $k++) {
        do {
            $regel = rand(($rijen + 1)*10, (($rijen + 1)*10)+9);
        } while(in_array($regel, $kaart[$rijen]));
        $kaart[$rijen][$k] = $regel;
}
}
$trekking = array();
$DeControlerij = false;
$DeControlecol = false;
do {
    do {
        $rijen = rand(10, 69);
    } while(in_array($rijen, $trekking));
    $trekking[] = $rijen;
} while(!ishetBingo($kaart, $trekking, $DeControlerij, $DeControlecol));
// teken kaart en bewaar score
$columns=[];
echo "<table style='border:1px solid blue;'>";
foreach ($kaart as $rijkey => $tabelrij) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $iter = 0;
    $weggestreept = 0;
    foreach ($tabelrij as $colkey => $cel) {
        // bewaar nummer v/d cell
        if(!key_exists($iter,$columns)){
            $columns[$iter]=0;
        }
        if (in_array($cel, $trekking)) {
            if($DeControlerij!==false && $DeControlerij ==$rijkey){
                echo "<td style='background:green;color:white;border:1px solid black;'>" . $cel . "</td>";
            }
            elseif($DeControlecol!==false && $DeControlecol==$colkey){
                echo "<td style='background:green;color:white;border:1px solid black;'>" . $cel . "</td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td style='background:blue;color:white;border:1px solid black;'>" . $cel . "</td>";
            }
            $weggestreept++;
            $columns[$iter]++;
        } 
        else {
            //$columns[$iter] += 0;
            echo "<td>" . $cel . "</td>";
        }
        $iter++;

    }
    echo "<td>" . $weggestreept . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $field){
    echo '<td>'.$field.'</td>';
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
// Bingo melding
// if (ishetBingo($kaart, $trekking)) {
//     echo '<h2>BINGO!!!</h2>';
// };
// print trekking
echo "<br />Getrokken getallen:<table><tr>";
foreach ($trekking as $nummer) {
    if (in_array($nummer, $trekking)) {
    echo "<td>" . $nummer . "</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
echo "<br/>Aantal getallen dat getrokken is: " . count($trekking);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the array first, and then print it in html.
Something like:

```
$rows = array();
for($r = 1; $r <= 6; $r++) {
    $rows[$r] = array();
    for($c = 0; $c < 6; $c++) {
        do {
            $t = rand($r * 10, ($r * 10) + 9);
        } while(in_array($t, $rows[$r]));
        $rows[$r][$c] = $t;
    }
}
```

The trick part is the "in_array" part :)

And then you just print it:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

And a full example, with the draw array:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Bingo</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php


$rows = array();
for($r = 1; $r <= 6; $r++) {
    $rows[$r] = array();
    for($c = 0; $c < 6; $c++) {
        do {
            $t = rand($r * 10, ($r * 10) + 9);
        } while(in_array($t, $rows[$r]));
        $rows[$r][$c] = $t;
    }
}

$draw = array();

$full = false;
do {
    do {
        $r = rand(1, 70);
    } while(in_array($r, $draw));
    $draw[] = $r;

    $cRows = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);
    $cCols = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

        foreach($rows as $row => $cols) {
        foreach($cols as $col => $number) {
            if(in_array($number, $draw)) {
                $cRows[$row]++;
                $cCols[$col]++;

                if($cRows[$row] == 6 || $cCols[$col] == 6) $full = true;
            }
        }
    }

} while(!$full);

echo 'Numbers are: ' . implode(', ', $draw);

echo '<br /><br /><table>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo '<td';
        if(in_array($cell, $draw)) echo ' style="color: white; background-color: blue;"';
        echo '>' . $cell . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dionei. Now the table is generated (see updated code); I want to generate a bingo draw that will generate random numbers:, i have updated the code by

Comment: Now the table is generated (see updated code); I want to generate a bingo draw that will generate random numbers. There must be four conditions for the draw: 1) numbers between 1 and 70; 2) if the generated numbers are contained in the generated table, the cell must be colored in blue; 3) only the generated numbers of the draw that are contained in the table will be saved and printed in an array 4) if a generated number is repeated, this will not be saved in the printed list of point 3. What I am doing is trial/error and I still do not know if this is good qua syntax and approach.

Comment: I think its not clear what you really need.. you want to draw the table html, and after that generate the numbers?

Comment: Hey; what I try in my updated code is to generate a bingo draw that will influence the table, so the table can be printed out with the colored cells. As soon as a row or a column is completely colored, the bingo draw should stop because it is bingo (it is sufficient with one colored row or column)

Comment: It will be easier to generate an array with the "card numbers", then another array with the "bingo draw", and then just compare both. 

I'm editing the answer with a new code.

Comment: Hey Dionel; I see that the draw stops without having one complete row or column colored in blue; how can it be assured that the draw during the first attempt will continue until only one row or column is all colored in blue?

Comment: Ok, now I understood what you need to achive. Changed the code to solve it.. take a look.

Comment: Hey Dionel; how can you assure that the whole colored row or column (that has formed the BINGO) becomes green? The other blue colored cells can remain blue; There should be a 7th row and a 7th column in the table that stores the number of colored cells in the respective row and column (how many cells in the respective column and cell have been coloured as blue, including the green one) but this 7th row and 7th column should be shown on the screen :)

Comment: correction: the 7th column and the 7th row should not be shown on the screen :)

Comment: Last mentions were solved already :) How can I transform the ishetBingo function in a simple php statement?. I am not allowed to use functions in this piece of code. At the other hand, I am only allowed to use functions in two moments of the bingo. 1) for filling in the table and return it, and 2) for printing the table. How to transform the statements in functions in these two pieces of code? (code has been updated)

Comment: you can just put the function code before the while and use the $full flag in the loop, as while(!$full)

Comment: Hi Dionei; i was told that the size of the table was already known at the begin of the game, and therefore I should not use foreach; what should I use then?

Comment: you can replace foreach loops with for loops

Comment: Hi Dionel; if I replace the foreach loop in for loops in 'foreach($rows as $row => $cols)' and in 'foreach($cols as $col => $number)' I get then a white screen; what do I miss still?